# jquery remove class from parent div

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I would like to remove the "open" class from the parent when i close the toggle, however my code below is not working. It adds the "open" class but is not removing when it closes. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

```
$('.sub-menu').hide();
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    if (!$(".sub-menu").is(":visible"))
        $(this).addClass("open");

    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle(function () {
        if (!$(".sub-menu").is(":visible"))
            $(this).parent('.toggle').removeClass("open");
    });

});
```

Update: HTML for the "nav" is below as requested.

```
<dd class="toggle open">
    <a id="navProducts">Products</a>
</dd>
<div class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">    
   <dd class="sub-menu-option">
     <a id="navBluray" href="nhdadmin/products/bluray">Blu-ray</a>
   </dd>
   <dd class="sub-menu-option">
     <a id="navXbox" href="nhdadmin/products/xbox">Xbox</a>
   </dd>
   <dd class="sub-menu-option">
     <a id="navPlayStation" href="nhdadmin/products/playstation">PlayStation</a>
   </dd>
```

Comment: could you give us some html to work with please?

Comment: Might this be the problem?

http://jqueryminute.com/jquery-parent-vs-parents/

Comment: Seems to me, since you're using .next() to target .sub-menu, it's not a child element of .toggle, but a sibling. But it's just guessing really without any HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
   if (!$(".sub-menu").is(":visible"))
       $(this).addClass("open");

   var currentSlide = $(this);
   $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle(function () {
       if (!$(".sub-menu").is(":visible"))
           currentSlide.removeClass("open");
   });
});
```

Comment: This does the same thing as my answer, but with an extra variable.

Comment: but I had code, all programmers don't speak english.
less yada-yada, more code

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the "open" class to `.toggle` elements on click. You then try to remove it from `$(this)` (toggle element) `.parent('.toggle')` (toggle element's parent of class "toggle" - nonexistent).

Remove the `.parent('.toggle')`, and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.sub-menu').hide();
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    var toggle = $(this);

    toggle.next('.sub-menu').slideToggle(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")){
            toggle.addClass("open");
        } else {
            toggle.removeClass("open");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Also worked well, i chose the other solution though as it adds the CSS before the menu opens, and after it closes :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).parent('.toggle').removeClass("open");
```

instead

```
$(this).prev('.toggle').removeClass("open");
```

Hope it will help